# Django password change view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to implement password changing in my django app, with my own template and form. So i decided to create my own view function instead of using django's. The problem Im having is the change password page doesn't change the password. My form just reloads and shows one error 'something went wrong' you can see the if statement it comes from in my chgpwd.html template. I'm not sure if there is another way I should be implementing errors on this template but thats all it shows me. The werid thing is I used my same view with the django supplied form and it worked but as soon as i plugged in my template and form it stops working. I can't figure out what my problem is and could really use some help, thanks.

chgpwd.html template

```
{%extends 'auth_base.html'%}
{%load static%}
{%block title%} CX Labs SOC LogIn {% endblock%}
{%block content%}
<div class="wrapper" style="max-width:450px">
    {%if form.errors %}
    <p style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:30px; color:red;">something went wrong</p>
    {%endif%}

    <div class="logo"> <img src="{%static 'website/cxlabs.jpg'%}" alt=""> </div>
    <div class="text-center mt-4 name"> CXLabs SOC <br/> Password Change</div>
    <form method="post" class="p-3 mt-3">
        <div class="form-field d-flex align-items-center"> <span class="far fa-user"></span> {{form.oldPwd}} </div>
        <div class="form-field d-flex align-items-center"> <span class="far fa-user"></span> {{form.newPwd1}} </div>
        <div class="form-field d-flex align-items-center"> <span class="fas fa-key"></span> {{form.newPwd2}} </div> <button type="submit" class="btn mt-3">Change Password</button>
        {%csrf_token%}
    </form>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

Urls.py

```
import django
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as av
from django.urls import path, include
from authentication.forms import CustomAuthForm, CustomPwdChgForm
from website import views
from authentication import views as authv

urlpatterns = [
    path('logout/', av.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logout.html',
         next_page=None), name='logout'),
    path('chgpwd/', authv.changepwview, name='chgpwd'),
    path('sign/', include('sign.urls')),
    path('download/<int:id>', views.zip_download, name='zipDL')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView
from authentication.forms import CustomPwdChgForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from website import views
from django.apps import apps


# Create your views here.




def changepwview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomPwdChgForm(user=request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
            # messages.success(request,
            #                  'Your password was successfully updated!',
            #                  extra_tags='alert-success')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CustomPwdChgForm(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'registration/chgpwd.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput


class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))


class CustomPwdChgForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    oldPwd = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Old Password'}))
    newPwd1 = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'New Password'}))
    newPwd2 = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'New Password'}))

    class meta:
        model = User
```

Answer (score 1):

The form.is_valid () function expects an input field with the "name" attribute = "old_password". If it does not find it because, like in your case, the "name" attribute is different ("oldPwd"), the validation fails.
I do not know if the same applies to the new password and new password confirmation fields; Django's form names are "new_password1" and "new_password2" respectively.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to implement change passwords without using django forms but html traditional forms, you can follow this method i'm dropping here.

## views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ChangePasswordView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'users/change_password.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("user_profile")

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        old_password: str = request.POST.get("old_password")
        new_password1: str = request.POST.get('new_password1')
        new_password2: str = request.POST.get('new_password2')

        user: CustomUser = request.user

        if not user.check_password(old_password):
            messages.warning(request, "old password doesn't match.")
            return redirect("change_password")

        if len(new_password1) < 10:
            messages.warning(request, "password length should not be less than 10.")
            return redirect("change_password")

        if old_password == new_password1:
            messages.warning(request, "your new password cannot be the same as your old password.")
            return redirect("change_password")

        if new_password1 != new_password2:
            messages.warning(request, "new_password1 and new_password2 do not match.")
            return redirect("change_password")

        user.set_password(new_password1)
        user.save()
        update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
        messages.success(request, "password change successfull. your new password would take effect on next login.")
        return redirect("user_profile")
```

This is tested and confirmed working with django 4.2.7.